# Flask как вернуть статус и продолжить обрабатывать данные?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, flask

У меня бот встроен в flask для обработки вебхуков от телеграмм:

```
@app.route('/tgwh', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    """If we get webhook from TG handle data and response 200 """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json(force=False, silent=False, cache=True)
        d.handling_data(data)
    return jsonify(result={"status": 200})
```

Операция обработки данных потенциально может затянуться
`d.handling_data(data)`.
Что можно сделать для того, чтобы сначала вернуть 200-й статус, а потом обработать данные?

Comment: Запустить обработку в процессе отдельном от Flask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007099/return-http-status-code-from-flask-without-returning, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767144/returning-a-status-code-early-for-a-time-consuming-function-in-flask